# how to get the same coordinates from source.XYZ and source.VectorTile

Tags: openlayers

my map has two layers, one is XYZ tile layer, and the other is vector tile layer. what makes me confused is the formatted url of these two layers had been filled with different x, y, z params, how can i make them the same. the code is as below:

```
const map = new Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
    new TileLayer({
        title: "Google Satellite",
        source: new XYZ({ url: 'http://mt1.google.cn/vt/lyrs=s&hl=pl&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
    }),
    new VectorTileLayer({
        style:styleFunction,
        source: new VectorTileSource({
            url: 'http://localhost/features?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
            format: new GeoJSON({
                featureProjection:"EPSG:4326",
                extractStyles: false,
            }),
            minZoom: 13,
            maxZoom: 13,
        }),
    }),
],
view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [130.78267,16.065669],
    minZoom:13,
    zoom: 13
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

correct view projection as follows and worked finally

```
view: new View({
    center: transform([130.78267,16.065669],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
    minZoom:13,
    zoom: 13
})
```